# DataTable в DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datatable

Есть вот такой участок кода и форма с DataGridView:

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreditData helper = new CreditData();
        double cash = helper.sumCredit;
        double percent = helper._percent;
        if(helper.ann == 0)
        {
            double commonPay = helper.comm;
        }
        else
        {
            double coeffAnn = helper.ann;
            percent /= 12;// % 1 mnth
            percent /= 100;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("Місяць", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Сума щомісячного платежу", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("%", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("Погашення основної суми кредиту", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("Залишок позики", typeof(double));

            for(int k = 0; k < helper.termin; k++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(k + 1, coeffAnn, percent * cash, coeffAnn - (percent * cash), cash - (coeffAnn - (percent * cash)));
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
    }
```

CreditData - класс, который переносит данные из одной формы в другую.
Мне нужно вывести значения в DataGridView, для этого использую DataTable.
 Делал по примеру в инете - вроде как все должно работать, но при запуске таблица пустая(ни колонок, ни столбцов, темболее нет значений).
Подскажите как исправить.
P. S. Расчеты в строках немного не правильны, я в курсе.

Прилагаю новую инфу: код первой формы + код класса

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double start_sum;
        double interest_rate;
        double donation;
        int term;
        bool checking = true;
        CreditData helper = new CreditData();
        //test: Is you dork or no?
        try
        {
            term = Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            start_sum = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            interest_rate = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            donation = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!\nBe more attentive, please!\nYou made a mistake!");
            checking = false;
        }
        bool checking_comboBox;
        bool checking_zero = true;
        if(checking != false)
        {
            if ((start_sum = double.Parse(textBox4.Text)) == 0
            || (interest_rate = double.Parse(textBox1.Text)) == 0
            || (donation = double.Parse(textBox2.Text)) == 0
            || (term = Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error!\nYou cannot enter 0!");
                checking_zero = false;
            }
        }

        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1) checking_comboBox = true;
        else checking_comboBox = false;

        if (checking == false || checking_zero == false || checking_comboBox == false)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
        }
        //end test
        else if (checking_zero == true && checking == true && checking_comboBox == true)
        {
            start_sum = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            interest_rate = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            donation = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            term = Int32.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            textBox3.Text = (start_sum = start_sum - donation).ToString();
            helper.sumCredit = start_sum;
            helper._percent = interest_rate;
            helper.termin = term;
            helper.ann = 0;
            helper.comm = 0;
            Form2 _show = new Form2();
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                helper.ann = Annuity(start_sum, interest_rate, term);
                _show.Show();
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                helper.comm = CommonMethod(start_sum, term);
                _show.Show();
            } 

        }
    }
    double Annuity(double _startSum, double _interestRate, int _term)
    {
        double coefficientAnnuity = (_interestRate / 100) / 12 * Math.Pow((1 + (_interestRate / 100) / 12), _term) / (Math.Pow((1 + (_interestRate / 100) / 12), _term) - 1);
        coefficientAnnuity = _startSum * coefficientAnnuity;//тіло кредиту з відсотками
        return coefficientAnnuity;
    }
    double CommonMethod(double _startSum, int _term)
    {
        double monthlyPay = _startSum / _term;
        return monthlyPay;
    }
}
```

Класс:

```
class CreditData
{
    public double sumCredit { get; set; }
    public double _percent { get; set; }
    public double ann { get; set; } 
    public double comm { get; set; }
    public int termin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Появилась новая инфа - дело в том, что не выполняется условие: то есть в первой форме рассчитывется helper.ann и записывается в класс, но при вызове .ann во второй форме это поле почему-то остается равно 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена!** 
 Прошу прощения за беспокойство.
**Значит в чём была ошибка?**

- сохранял данные в класс.
  1. А именно, чтоб обратится к классу нужно создавать объект класса. Из этого вытекает, что чтобы взять эти данные нужно опять обращатся к этому классу => опять создание объекта этого класса но уже в другой форме. Но постойте, это же 2 разных объекта.
  2. В этом вся и загвоздка я брал данные совсем другого объекта, а не того которого я создавал в первой форме. Соответственно условие выполнялось неверно(которое прописано в Form2).

**Как решил?**

- прошёлся дебагом по коду и понял, что данные из класса не доходят до Form2, но все таки сохраняются в классе. Значит дело не в выводе данных в таблицу, а способе передачи данных из одной формы в другую.
- почитал полезную статейку о передачи данных с одной формы в другую.
- нашёл подходящий способ и переписал несколько строчек кода.

**Готово!**

Comment: в справке было сказано, что можно редактировать с помощью HTML, а в итоге оно не принимало и считало, что это не правильно оформлен код...